# Movie about huge spiders from some planet

Tags: identify-this-movie

Watched this in color, English, somewhat decent quality. I can't remember the year.

- The movie is about a fight b/w Humans and some kind of spiders.
- These spiders come all the way from their planet to Earth and wreak havoc in Brazil, killing the protagonist's parents.
- The humans then mount an assault with, I remember, exactly 100,000 men on the planet of these spiders.
- It is shown that none of these soldiers make it back and the humans realizing that these spiders are smarter than they thought.

I'm terribly sorry, this is all I know.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This might be [Starship Troopers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (1997)

- Aliens have a sub-type called 'Arachnids' (picture below)
- Protagonists parents live in Buenos Aires (which is later destroyed by the aliens)
- Troopers take the battle to the bug's planet
- The aliens have a leader (big blobby looking thing that controls the rest of the aliens)

[image]
[Source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/475059460672871733/)

The points seem to fit.

Comment: Definitely it. Beat me to it!

Comment: The "spiders" don't actually come to Earth. They sent an asteroid to Earth and the asteroid destroyed Buenos Aires. Also note that the 1997 movie is loosely based on the book of the same title by Robert A. Heinlein. As usual, the book is much better.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, in the Heinlein novel, the protagonist is Filipino, not Brazilian.

Comment: Yep, this is it.

Comment: FYI - Just recently been 4K blu-ray remastered.

Comment: @RossPresser And I heard the love interest (Dizzy) in the book is the opposite sex and dies in the first chapter. :D